# How to create a circle-shaped image that emits a color light effect that runs in all browsers?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, webkit

I was working on [this website](http://gibis.unifesp.br/sibgrapi16/Invited_Speakers.php), which uses `bootstrap`. On it there are circle-shaped images and when the mouse hovers I want to create an effect of that picture as creating a color light. For that, I used `box-shadow` because shadows wouldn't interfere within the image. The code looks like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-3" id="af">
  <br/><br/><br/>
  <center>
  <img src="OnePicture.jpg" class="img-circle smallpic"/>
  </center>
  <!-- The div continues with text -->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.smallpic{
  max-width:100px;
  max-height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid transparent;

  /*Trying to force GPU Acceleration*/

  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  -o-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);        

  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease;
  transition: all 1s;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
}
#af:hover .smallpic{
    border: 3px solid #E3000E;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    -moz-box-shadow:  0 0  500px 100px #E3000E;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0  500px 100px #E3000E;
    box-shadow: 0 0  500px 100px #E3000E;
}
```

This code did exactly what I want, but due to a `Webkit` bug, it won't work properly on any Webkit based browser, which includes the popular `Google Chrome`.

Here is the result in Google Chrome: [link](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=15850F3F03385D22!300834&authkey=!ABGbwMAPnsZqcjQ&v=3&ithint=photo%2Cpng)

In my tests, the code worked really well in `Mozilla Firefox`, `Microsoft Edge` and also `Internet Explorer`. But `Google Chrome`, `Vivaldi` and other webkit based browsers tested got the same buggy look. Is there another way to make that effect work in all browsers besides `box-shadow` usage?

Comment: It's a bug in chrome: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=30475

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But it is still possible to have the same behaviour in all browsers. You need just to modify your HTML and CSS.

Here the example HTML

```
<div class="wrapper red">
  <div class="image"></div>
  <h2>Red</h2>
</div>
<div class="wrapper blue">
  <div class="image"></div>
  <h2>Blue</h2>
</div>
<div class="wrapper green">
  <div class="image"></div>
  <h2>Green</h2>
</div>
```

Here the example CSS:

```
.wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.wrapper:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: ' ';
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  transition: all 2s;
}

.blue:before {
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(0, 0, 255, .7) 10%, rgba(0, 0, 255, 0) 70%);
  opacity: 0;
}

.red:before {
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(255, 0, 0, .7) 10%, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0) 70%);
  opacity: 0;
}

.green:before {
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(0, 255, 0, .7) 10%, rgba(0, 255, 0, 0) 70%);
  opacity: 0;
}

.wrapper:hover:before {
  opacity: 1;
}

.image {
  margin: 100px auto 0;
  border: 4px solid red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.green .image {
  border-color: rgb(0, 255, 0);
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, .3);
}

.red .image {
  border-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, .3);
}

.blue .image {
  border-color: rgb(0, 0, 255);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, .3);
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Here a live [demo](http://codepen.io/jannahody/full/dMeded/)

Comment: Thank you, but won't this code confine the light effect get confined inside the wrapper? I would rather the light to interfere in elements outside the wrapper, yet I still don't know how to make it. Again, thank you for your help

Comment: Interfere the light in elements outside the wrapper it's not possible cause of the Crome Bug. Maybe later when the Bug is fixed.